# Postgres split and convert string value to composite array

Tags: postgresql

I have a Type with below structure.

`create type t_attr as (id character varying(50), data character varying(100)`);

I get text/varchar value through a user-defined function. The value looks like below.

```
txt := 'id1#data1' , 'id2#data2';
```

(In the above example, there are 2 values separated by comma, **but the count will vary**).

I'm trying to store each set into the t_attr array using the below code. Since each set will contain a `#` as separator I use it to split the id and data values. **For testing purpose I have used only one set below**.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  attr_array t_attr[];
  txt text := 'id1#data1';
BEGIN
  attr_array[1] := regexp_split_to_array(txt, '#');
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But the above code throws error saying `'malformed record literal'` and `'missing left paranthesis'`.
Can someone please help on how to store this data into array? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are trying to assign an array value to the record. Try:

```
do $$
declare
    attr_array t_attr[];
    txt text := 'id1#data1';
begin
    attr_array[1] := (split_part(txt, '#', 1), split_part(txt, '#', 2));
    raise info '%', attr_array;
end $$;
```

Output:

```
INFO:  {"(id1,data1)"}
DO
```

However if you really need to split values using arrays:

```
do $$
declare
    a text[];
begin
    ....
    a := regexp_split_to_array(txt, '#');
    attr_array[1] := (a[1], a[2]);
end $$;
```